# Multilingual E-Commerce website

Tags: e-commerce

I am about to start a medium e-commerce site (+-200 items). The site must be in French and English. I have tried and tested wordpress with WPLM and shopp which is a plugin solution. The question, do you know a real, nice, working, complete e-commerce system, that works great in multiple languages, for less that 200$ (free is better)? I can do php, css, and html, but tweaking other code is not my favorite game.

Comment: I will suggest you to use [Storehippo](http://www.storehippo.com),they are offering more features on affordable price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.prestashop.com/ originates from French and it's multilingual.
(I have no experience with using it, just evaluating it as possibility right now)

(would like to hear from more experienced people how PrestaShop can go really wrong and what should I watch for, so far I see lot of positive feedback everywhere with just minor things against it)